# Explanation concerning demonstration that an infinite subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Every infinite subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.

**Proof.** Let A be a denumerable set and let B be an infinite subset of A. Since A is denumerable, we can write $A = \{a_1, \dotsc \}$. Let $S = \{i \in \mathbb{N} \, : \, a_i \in B \}$. First, we use induction to show that B contains a denumerable subset.Since S is nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$, it follows from the Well-Ordering Principle that S has a least element, say $i_1$. Let $b_1 = a_{i_1}$. Let $S_1 = S - \{i_1\}$. Since $S_1 \neq \varnothing$ (indeed, $S_1$ is infinite), $S_1$ has a least element, say $i_2$. Let $b_2 = a_{i_2}$, which, of course, is distinct from $b_1$. Assume that for an arbitrary integer $k \geq 2$, the (distinct) elements $b_1, b_2, \dotsc, b_k$ have been defined by $b_j = a_{i_j}$ for each integer $j$ with $1 \leq j \leq k$, where $i_1$ is the smallest element in $S$ and $i_j$ is the minimum element of $S_k = S - \{i_1, \dotsc, i_k\}$ for $2 \leq j \leq k$. Now let $i_{k+1}$ be the minimum element of $S_k = S- \{i_1, \dotsc, i_k\}$ and let $b_{k+1} = a_{i_{k+1}}$. Hence it follows that for each integer $n \geq 2$, an elment $b_n$ belongs to B that is distinct from $b_1, \dotsc, b_{n-1}$. Thus we have exhibited the elements $\{b_1, \dotsc$} in B.

Let $B' = \{b_1, \dotsc\}$. Certainly, $B' = B$. Let $b \in B$. Since $B \subseteq A$, it follows that $b = a_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $n \in S$. If $n = i_1$, then $b = b_1 = a_n$ and so $b \in B'
$. Thus we may assume that $n > i_1$. Let $S'$ consist of those positive integers less than $n$ that belong to $S$. Since $n > i_1$ and $i_1 \in S$, it follows that $S' \neq \varnothing$. Certainly, $1 \leq |S'| \leq n-1$; so $S'$ is finite. Thus $|S'| = m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. The set $S'$ therefore consists of the $m$ smallest integers of $S$, that is $S' = \{i_1, \dotsc, i_m\}$. The smallest integer that belongs to S and is greater than $i_m$ must be $i_{m+1}$, of course, and $i_{m+1} \geq n$. But $n \in S$, so $n = i_{m+1}$ and $b = a_n = a_{{i_m+1}} \in B'$. Hence $B = B' = \{b_1, \dotsc\}$, which is denumerable.

$\blacksquare$

I have two questions regarding this proof. I essentially understand the demonstration, but there are two points that confuse me.

1. The second part of the proof demonstrates that $B = B'$, where $B' = \{b_1, b_2, \dotsc\}$, but I do not understand why we need to show this set equality in the first place. The only explanation in the book is, "Are we certain that $B' = B$?" But why does this matter? If we have found all the elements in $A$ that also belong to $B$, and we were able to list these elements $b_1, b_2, \dotsc$, then $B$ is denumerable.
2. I see the two instances where PMI were used, but I do not perceive where each inductive hypothesis was employed in the inductive step. Would someone enlighten me as to their integration in the proof?

Any reasonable insight is appreciated.

Comment: For 1) I think the point is that it's not clear that you've found all the elements of $A$ that also belong to $B$.  I don't really understand the question about 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we were able to list these elements $b_1,b_2,\ldots$

Those elements are the elements of $B'$ by definition. They are an enumeration of $B'$, so they prove that $B'$ is denumerable. But if $B' \ne B$, then it would fail to show that $B$ is denumerable, since there would be points of $B$ not picked up by the enumeration. Thus it is necessary to show $B' = B$.

> I see the two instances where PMI were used, but I do not perceive where each inductive hypothesis was employed in the inductive step. Would someone enlighten me as to their integration in the proof?

Based on the rest of this question, I would assume that "PMI" means induction, except that induction is only used once in the proof. (Please avoid using unexplained abbreviations, very few abbrevations in Math are universal.) The induction hypothesis is

> Assume that for an arbitrary integer $k\ge2$, the (distinct) elements $b_1,b_2,…,b_k$ have been defined by $b_j=a_{i_j}$ for each integer $j$ with $1\le j\le k$, where $i_1$ is the smallest element in $S$ and $i_j$ is the minimum element of $S_k=S−\{i_1,…,i_k\}$ for $2\le j\le k$.

In particular, it assumes that the integers ${i_j}$ have been defined for $j\le k$. This allows the subsequent definitions of $b_j = a_{i_j}$ and $S_k=S−\{i_1,…,i_k\}$. The hypothesis is then used in the next statement:

> Now let $i_{k+1}$ be the minimum element of $S_k$

This definition is not possible without defining $S_k$ first.