# Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are denumerable sets then $A\cup B$ is denumerable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

What I have done is the following:

As $A$ and $B$ are denumerable sets then there are two bijections $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$, $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow B$ therefore, find the following function that goes from the naturals to the union of $A$ and $B$

$$h(n)=\begin{cases}f\left(\frac{n+1}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\g\left(\frac{n}2\right),&\text{if }n\text{ is even,}\end{cases}$$

I was able to prove successfully that this function is injective, but I have not been able to find the surjective, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that $h(n)=f(\frac{n+1}{2})$ for $n$ odd assumes that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. If $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, then $h(n)$ must instead be defined to be $f(\frac{n-1}{2})$ for $n$ odd. Also, $h(\frac{n}{2})$ is a typo and should be replaced with $g(\frac{n}{2})$. Finally, $h$ is injective only if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang This function surjective? how do I verify it, that is not clear to me, any help?

Comment: This isn't injective if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.  (If $x\in A\cap B$ then there are $k,j$ so that $f(j)=g(k)=x$ and take $n=2j-1$ and $m= 2k$ then $h(n) = f(j)=g(k) = h(m)$ but $m\ne n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that in your two cases you used the function $h$ in one of them where I think you intended $g$.

Next note that in fact $h$ is not injective if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.  I would suggest that the way to handle this is to first prove the theorem with the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and then use this result to prove it for the more general setting.

Finally, surjectivity:  Let $x\in A\cup B$.  Consider cases, $x\in A$ or $x\in B$ and first assume $x\in A$. Then there is some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n) = x$ by the surjectivity of $f$.  But then we may consider

$$ h\left(2n-1\right)= f\left(\frac{2n-1+1}{2}\right) = f(n) = x $$

That handles the assumption that $x\in A$ and the case where $x\in B$ is similar.

Comment: Your remarks are ideal, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative solution. You may find it more straightforward.

Let $A,B$ be denumerable. Let $C=B-A$. Then $A \cup B$ = $A \cup C$.

Now, it follows that $A \cap C = \emptyset$.

Case 1) $C$ is infinite. Then $C \subseteq B$.

Since $B$ is denumerable, $\exists$ $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$ which is a bijection. [Explanation concerning demonstration that an infinite subset of a denumerable set is denumerable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548044/explanation-concerning-demonstration-that-an-infinite-subset-of-a-denumerable-se)

Now, $A \cap C = \emptyset$ and $A,C$ are denumerable. Let $A \cap C =$ {$a_1,c_1,a_2,c_2,a_3,c_3,...$}.

Therefore, $A \cup C$ is denumerable.

Case 2) $C$ is finite. Then $C=${$c_1,c_2,...,c_k$}

Now, by assumption, $A=${$a_1,a_2,a_3,...$} is denumerable.

Now, let the element after $c_k$ be $a_1$ Then $a_2,a_3...$

Therefore, $A \cup C =$ {$c_1,c_2,...,c_k,a_1,a_2,a_3,...$} is denumerable.

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the union of denumerable sets is denumerable, but that's precisely what we're asked to prove. It's circular reasoning.

Comment: "Therefore, $C$ is denumerable. Therefore $A \cup C$ is denumerable."

Comment: @jgd1729 I was using the theorem that if $A \subseteq B$ where $B$ is denumerable and $A$ is infinite, then $A$ is denumerable. I have added that statement without proof, as it has been proved on this site before. Here is one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548044/explanation-concerning-demonstration-that-an-infinite-subset-of-a-denumerable-se

Comment: That isn't the issue. I'm not arguing with the claim that $C$ is denumerable. I'm saying that you have claimed that since $A$ and $C$ are both denumerable, it must be that $A\cup C$ is denumerable. This is true, but it's the exact thing you're supposed to be proving. 

Also, to be clear, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @jgd1729 Edited: is it better now?

Comment: Better, but now you're basically doing what the OP suggested, but without the same level of precision or rigor.

Comment: I agree, but I think deconstructing a problem using less rigorous terminology is one method to prepare a more meticulous proof.